# .NET CF component with ActiveSync Protocol

Tags: vb.net, compact-framework, activesync, .net-cf-3.5, exchange-server-2013

I am looking a **.NET CF component** that supports **Microsoft ActiveSync protocol** v 2.x, on port 443 with Exchange 2013 email server for **Motorola MC65**.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no such component. If you like to start/stop sync the mobile outlook eMail with an Exchange Server, you just need to use the OOM (outlook object model). ActiveSync is only envolved if you do connect the device with PC and provides the 'network' connection to your network and have a local Outlook that needs to be synced.
If you have a WiFi connection, you can sync eMail etc. using this and OOM. Whereas ActiveSync not only syncs eMail but also files on your PC.

repllog.exe (the mobile ActiveSync app) can be started with arguments to iniate a sync

/remote

which appears just to start the Activesync application and brings it to the foreground

/remote /all

which starts the Activesync application, brings it to the foreground and starts synchronising

/remote /all /h

which starts the Activesync application and starts synchronising without bringing it to the foreground